# Load more mysql results without updating whole page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am loading a query where I maximum want to show 3 result in a div.
Below code is working fine for just that. 
It is likewise working fine when I want to go to next page and load 3 more.

Only issues is that whole page are updating everytime I go back and forward.
Can someone help me with this solutions, so when I go back a forward only the div is updated with the new results, and the whole page is not updating, but just staying like it is. Thank you

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="infobox-large">

    <?
    $con = connectDB();
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die($query."<br/> 
    <br/>".mysql_error());
    $user_id = mysql_result($result, 0);


    // Sætter maks antal pr side
    $offset = (isset($_GET['offset'])) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0; // Hvis ikke 
    $offset er sat, sættes den til 0
    $pr_side = 3; // Antal resultater pr. side

    // Tæller antal poster i databasen
    $tael = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS antal from tb_user_tip where 
    user_id = '".$user_id."' and point=''") or die (mysql_error());
    $antal = mysql_result($tael,0);

    $limit = 3;
    $pages = ceil($antal/$limit);

    if(isset($_GET['offset']) && is_numeric($_GET['offset'])){
        if($_GET['offset'] < 1){
            $offset = 1;
        }elseif($_GET['offset'] > $pages){
            $offset = $pages;
        }else{
            $offset = intval($_GET['offset']);
        }
    }else{
        $offset = 1;
    }


    $end  = $offset * $limit;
    $start = $end - $limit;
    ?>             

<span class="headline-box grey">Nuværende tips <?echo "(".$antal.")";?> 
</span><br /><br />          

<?
$sql_current = "select * from tb_user_tip where user_id = '".$user_id."' and 
point='' order by start_date_time ASC LIMIT $start,$pr_side";
$result = mysql_query($sql_current, $con);
$current_tip_array = array();
while($row_current = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $home = $row_current['home_name'];
    $away = $row_current['away_name'];

    $home_image_name = "";
    if (strpos(strtolower($home), " ") != false) {
        $arrName = split(" ", strtolower($home));
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrName) - 1; $i++) {
            $home_image_name = $home_image_name . $arrName[$i] . "-";
        }
        $home_image_name = $home_image_name . $arrName[sizeof($arrName) - 1] 
. ".png";
        //$home_image_name = $arrName[0]."-".$arrName[1].".png";
    } else {
        $home_image_name = strtolower($home) . ".png";
    }
    $away_image_name = "";
    if (strpos(strtolower($away), " ") != false) {
        $arrName = split(" ", strtolower($away));
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrName) - 1; $i++) {
            $away_image_name = $away_image_name . $arrName[$i] . "-";
        }
        $away_image_name = $away_image_name . $arrName[sizeof($arrName) - 1] 
. ".png";
        //$home_image_name = $arrName[0]."-".$arrName[1].".png";
    } else {
        $away_image_name = strtolower($away) . ".png";
    }

    $home_image = "/images/soccer/" . $home_image_name;
    $away_image = "/images/soccer/" . $away_image_name;
    $item_current = array(
        "event_id" => $row_current['event_id'],
        "home_name" => $row_current['home_name'],
        "away_name" => $row_current['away_name'],
        "start_date_time" => $row_current['start_date_time'],
        "league_name" => $row_current['league_name'],
        "market_style" => $row_current['market_style'],
        "odd_style" => $row_current['odd_style'],
        "odd" => $row_current['odd'],
        "tip_amount" => $row_current['tip_amount'],
        "home_image" => $home_image,
        "away_image" => $away_image
    );
    array_push($current_tip_array, $item_current);

    echo "<div class='tip-box neautral bg-white grey heading-in-box'>";
    //Tip left - home name, league
    echo "<div class='home text-left'><span class='large green 
bold'>".$row_current['home_name']."</span><br /><br />Liga<br /><span 
class='darkgreen tiny bold'>".$row_current['league_name']."</span></div>";

    //Tip center - date & time, logo home & away, market style, odds style    
    echo "<div class='logoodds'><span class='darkgreen tiny bold'>".$row_current['start_date_time']."</span><br /><br /><img src='../".$home_image."' class='HOME team_img'> - <img src='../".$away_image."' class='AWAY team_img'><br /><br /><span class='darkgreen small bold'>".$row_current['market_style']."<br />".$row_current['odd_style']."&nbsp;".$row_current['odd']."</span></div>";

    //Tip right - away name, tip amount
    echo "<div class='away text-right'><span class='large green bold'>".$row_current['away_name']."</span><br /><br />Indsats<br /><span class='darkgreen tiny bold'>".$row_current['tip_amount']."</span></div>";     
    echo "</div>";  

    }

    if($offset > 1)
    echo '<a href="?offset='.($offset-1).'"><img src="img/arrowbackgreen50.png" class="arrow_small"></a>';
    echo '' . $offset . ' af ' . $pages . '&nbsp;';
    if($offset < $pages)
    echo '<a href="?offset='.($offset+1).'"><img src="img/arrowgreen50.png" class="arrow_small"></a>';

    ?>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use `Ajax` for that or `Datatable`

Comment: you'd need to get the data via ajax then. Search for "ajax pagination" to find examples! (it's not so easily implemented into existing code to be answered here, so will be considered "too broad")

Comment: use ajax with pagination

Comment: you can use Datatable to load data with pagination without a re-loading whole page. see https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query`. Its' deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO